# Selecting duplicates from SQL server DB based on complex(?) criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

```
fileid  custid dept1 dept2      date1      date2      date3
123     456     2       4       1/1/04     1/1/05     1/1/06
777     456     2       4       NULL       5/30/05    1/1/07
111     456     2       4       12/2/06    NULL       3/3/07
200     456     2       6       1/1/04     2/1/04     3/1/04
444     456     2       8       2/1/07     4/1/07     6/1/07
500     456     2       8       3/1/07     3/15/07    4/2/07
```

I trying to write some SQL that would pull the first 3 records above and display them as a 'set'  based on the fact that the custid, dept1, and dept2 are  the same and also that the dates 'overlap' ie, any of the dates in fileid 123 are earlier than the earliest date in fileid 777 and fileid 111. It wouldn't pull the 4th record because dept2 is different.  And it would pull records 5 and 6 and display them as a separate set because custid, dept1, dept2 match and fileid 500's dates are 'inside' fileid 444's dates.  Been pounding my head against a wall with this one.  Can anyone help?

Here is an example of multiple rows with matching custiid, dept1 and dept2 not in the same set:

```
fileid  custid dept1 dept2      date1      date2      date3
123     456     2       4       1/1/04     1/1/05     1/1/06
777     456     2       4       NULL       5/30/05    1/1/07
111     456     2       4       12/2/06    NULL       3/3/07
666     456     2       4       1/1/08     3/1/08     5/1/08
```

fileid 666 is not in the set because its dates don't overlap with any of the others.

Comment: Can you add some the SQL you've tried so far?

Comment: also, can you give an example where there are multiple rows with matching custid, dept1 and dept2, but they are NOT all in the same set?

Comment: I'm extracting the code from a larger project , may take some time. Here is an example

Comment: @RossPresser, I edited main post to include an example  where there are multiple rows with matching custid, dept1 and dept2, but they are NOT all in the same set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that query gives your want. But i have to say this is not the cleanest answer. Also i get the conclusion in 3 query but it can be done with one query, but this will increase the complexity. In first query i find the duplicates in the second i list them and in the third i set the rules you want.

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM (Select custID,dept1,dept2 FROM @table 
Group By custID,dept1,dept2
HAVING COUNT(custID) > 1) AS p


SELECT * INTO #temp2 FROM (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY custID,dept1,dept2 Order By CustID ) as RN,* 
FROM @table 
Where custID IN (Select custID FROM #temp) AND dept1 IN (Select dept1 FROM #temp) AND dept2 IN (Select dept2 FROM #temp) 
) AS x


Select * FROM @table Where fileID IN (
Select t1.fileID FROM #temp2 t1
INNER JOIN #temp2 t2 ON t1.RN = t2.RN-1 AND (
COALESCE(t2.date1,t2.date2) BETWEEN COALESCE(t1.date1,t1.date2) AND COALESCE(t1.date3,t1.date2) 
OR
COALESCE(t2.date3,t2.date2) BETWEEN COALESCE(t1.date1,t1.date2) AND COALESCE(t1.date3,t1.date2) 
)
AND t2.custID = t1.custID AND t2.dept1 = t1.dept1 AND t2.dept2 = t1.dept2) 
OR 
fileID IN (
Select t2.fileID FROM #temp2 t1
INNER JOIN #temp2 t2 ON t1.RN = t2.RN-1 AND (
COALESCE(t2.date1,t2.date2) BETWEEN COALESCE(t1.date1,t1.date2) AND COALESCE(t1.date3,t1.date2) 
OR
COALESCE(t2.date3,t2.date2) BETWEEN COALESCE(t1.date1,t1.date2) AND COALESCE(t1.date3,t1.date2)
)
AND t2.custID = t1.custID AND t2.dept1 = t1.dept1 AND t2.dept2 = t1.dept2)
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/PJNA1240) is a live link to this solution.